# Finding pair values in a given range

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, c++14

I have an array or N pairs `(v1, v2)` where `v1 <= v2`. These are supposed to represent events in time that start at `v1` and end at `v2`. they can be equal, then the event is instantaneous. The array is sorted by starting time, `v1`.

For a given range `(L, R)`, I would like to find any pair where `L <= v1 <= R or L <= v2 <= R`. The idea here is to get events starting, happening or ending in the given range.

My main problem is efficiency. The array could contains hundreds of thousands of events. So just a linear search going through all pairs is not an option.

I read a bit about kd-tree but the problem with it is that it excludes the boundaries of the range and would only return `L <= v1 <= R AND L <= v2 <= R`. That is, would only return events that actually happen (start AND end) in the range whereas I need start OR end (or both obviously).

I thought also about keeping 2 lookup tables (I use double for time)

```cpp
std::map<double, Event*> startPoints;
std::map<double, Event*> endPoints;
```

and the use the `std::find` algorithm in both of them and merge the results.

Just looking for an advise, wether it's a good solution or if there is a more clever way.

EDIT:

Re-thinking about that, It is more complicated. Here is an example of the expected results

- L < R : Range is large enough

```
|---Ev1---|     |---Ev3---|     |---Ev5---|
        |---Ev2---|     |---Ev4---|
             |               |
             L               R
```

Here I would like to get Ev2 (which is ending in the range), Ev3 (Which is happening in the range and Ev4 (which is starting in the rage)

- L < R: Range too small for a complete event

```
|---Ev1---|     |---Ev3---|     |---Ev5---|
        |---Ev2---|     |---Ev4---|
                    |    |
                    L    R
```

Here I would like to get Ev3 as it is currently running in the range and Ev4 as it is starting in the range

- L == R: If I want to know what happens at one point in time

```
|---Ev1---|     |---Ev3---|     |---Ev5---|
        |---Ev2---|     |---Ev4---|
             |
             LR
```

Here I would like only Ev2 as it is the only one currently running.

Comment: Take a look at Boost.ICL.

Comment: Yeah, sorry I forgot to mention that. Boost is not an option as well, only stdlib

Comment: You could still take a look at Boost to see how they may accomplish your goal.  Then use those ideas to come up / research your own implementation.

Comment: I would recommend not using `std::map` but simply a sorted vector if you care about speed/memory overhead. Having a lookup like this for the starts and ends should be very efficient when used with `std::equal_range`. Merging the results from both lookups could be done with a simple `std::vector<Event*>` sorting + deduplicating.

Comment: Is the array of events static, so no insertions are expected?

Comment: You write `L <= v1 <= R or L <= v2 <= R` and then *starting, **happening** or ending* but that's not the same. For happening you need `v1 <= R and L <= v2`

Comment: @Yola: Yes the array is static, build before the search.
Also, I did, say `L <= v1 <= R or L <= v2 <= R` and that's the intended behaviour.
for example: https://pastebin.com/uTfidm0c 
I do want Ev2, Ev3 and Ev4 in the results. Ev2 is ending in the rand, Ev3 is happening in the range, Ev4 is starting in the range.

Comment: It is a classical logic OR where one of the two or both can be true to validate the result.

Comment: What about an event which starts before the interval starts and ends after the interval ends? E.g. interval [1,2], event [0,3].

Comment: @Yola: Just edited the first post with that in mind

Comment: Are you looking for an Interval Tree: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree?

Comment: I think that's it yes!

Comment: Do you need to _list_ the qualifying events, or just _count_ them?

Comment: I need to list them. See the problem as a timeline where you could look at a given point/range in time and get any event occurring during/at that time. I'm currently looking at interval trees as suggested by @Lawrence

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you need to handle three cases - *starting, happening or ending in the given range*, we can split it into three parts.

1. starting: `v1` lies in `[L,R]`.
2. ending: `v2` lies in `[L,R]`.

The third case can be formulated as `v1 <= R and L <= v2`, but the first two cases partially cover this case, so we will use different formulation to avoid collisions:

3. happening: `v1 < L and R < v2`

Well, it is easy to handle the first case in logarithmic plus number of reported events time if we can sort the array of events by `v1`. The same trick works for the second case.

The third case is trickier. Let's draw:

[image]

The pink area represents all intervals `L <= R`. The red dot is an interval and greenish area represents all possible events we want to capture. To do such a capture one can use [k2-tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree).

Comment: Thank you very much for that, I think this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree#Centered_interval_tree (thanks to Lawrence in the comment for that link) is more or less the same thing, I will inspire of both to implement that

Answer (score 1):

Using an indexed approach is fine - such as Boost.ICL solution.

That being said you could easily use a `std::vector` for this - even unsorted - I think for as long as you are within the range of some 100.000 or even 1.000.000 you should be fine (as long as you store actual values - not pointers in the vector as that can be slow) - exact numbers will of course depend on your thressholds.

```
struct MyEvent {
  double v1;//you use double for time
  double v2;
};


std::vector<MyEvent> events;
```

Here is an example using 1.000.000 elements:

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9a6d90348f6915e1

and the searching runs in 42 ms which consists of one compare and optional copy while your case may be a bit different it is comparable.

Going further, you could get more power by parallelizing your search in some way using eg. `std::for_each`.

Comment: `42 ms` is *a lot* in some contexts.

Comment: @fjardon indeed, it could be - which is why I wrote it depends on the pretext *and* about going further. The being said it will also cost to generate the index'es etc. which is why databases exists etc.

Answer (score -1):

`std::map` -->finding element complexity is O(logn)
If your keys are unique and you don't have a memory problem, you can use `std::unordered_map` which complexity is amortized (O1).
Also, you don't need to create 2 maps.
`std::unordered_map<double, std::pair<Event*, Event*>> StartEndPoints;`.
If your keys don't unique you can use `std::unordered_multimap`, but if your keys will be repeated a lot, the finding complexity could become (On).
I'll suggest not to pass key type as a `double`.

```
std::hash<double> hashing.
auto temp = hashing(key). // decltype of temp will be size_t
std::unordered_map<std::size_t, std::pair<Event*, Event*>> StartEndPoints;
```

Comment: `std::unordered_map` is not really suitable when you want to find a range of elements.

Comment: From the question, I understood that it is needed to find start and end points and not all elements in that points. If it is needed all elements in that range it is better to use ```std::vector``` as you suggested